# How can I find the closest counties of a US county if I have the Latitude and Longitude in R?

Tags: r, google-maps, geospatial

I know the function `sqrt((x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2)` to find the distance. But I have two columns of Latitude and Longitude and I want to find the variance between the 4 closest counties. 
Do I need a loop?
I have one more column with percentages. Every county has a percentage. So, I need to find the Variances of percentages between the closest counties.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: What do you mean by "variance" here? Statistical variance? If so, of what quantity of the counties?

Comment: You're using the Euclidean distance for a plane, but the distance on a sphere is different. The `geosphere` package has functions for this (see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32364246/496488), for example). You can also roll your own function: See [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/great-circle-distance-calculations-in-r/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585759/calculating-distances-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-r).

Comment: I am using 2D because I am going to do mapping after that.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you don't need to loop the problem.

Instead of doing this, you'd be better by creating an earth.dist function as follows:

```
earth.dist <- function (long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
{
rad <- pi/180
a1 <- lat1 * rad
a2 <- long1 * rad
b1 <- lat2 * rad
b2 <- long2 * rad
dlon <- b2 - a2
dlat <- b1 - a1
a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
R <- 6378.145
d <- R * c
return(d)
}
```

By combining this and the calculation between all the countries, you could order the list for each country by ascending distance, and afterwards computing the variance.
It would follows the result you are looking for.

Hope this functional explanation helps you.

Comment: I am using only US country. US country has states and a state has many counties.

Comment: In this case, I guess you can use counties instead. My best try without data is following next steps:
1. For each county compute the distances to all of them by using eath_dist + lapply.
2. Fetch first 4 rows only for each one. 
3. Compute de variance of distance for each one afterwards.