# Computing distances using distCosine

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to compute distances between couples of (lat,lon) coordinates, like in this example:
[Calculating distances from latitude and longitude coordinates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585759/calculating-distances-from-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-in-r)

but using dplyr in order to speed up the process, and using the distCosine function from geosphere.

This function accepts only vectors of size 2, and the only way I found that works is:

```
p <- data.frame(lat=runif(6,-90,90), lon=runif(6,-180,180),lat2=runif(6,-90,90), lon2=runif(6,-180,180) )
p$dist <- sapply(1:nrow(p), function(x) distCosine(c(p$lon[x], p$lat[x]), c(p$lon2[x], p$lat2[x]) ) )
```

With dplyr I have tried:

```
p %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(dist2prev = distCosine(c(lon, lat), c(lon2, lat2)))
p %>% group_by(1:n()) %>% mutate(dist2prev = distCosine(c(lon, lat), c(lon2, lat2)))
```

but the error is always the same:

```
Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
```

Any idea why dplyr does not succeed there?

Comment: worked for me as-is

Comment: this worked, too: `p %>% mutate(dist2prev = distCosine(cbind(lon, lat), cbind(lon2, lat2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your code isn't working. Using `do.call` seems to be orders of magnitude faster than your vanilla implementation or `dplyr`:

```
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)

N <- 100
p <- data.frame(lat=runif(N,-90,90), lon=runif(N,-180,180),
                lat2=runif(N,-90,90), lon2=runif(N,-180,180) )

f1 <- function() {
  sapply(1:nrow(p), function(x) distCosine(c(p$lon[x], p$lat[x]),
                                           c(p$lon2[x], p$lat2[x]) ) )
}

pts <- list(p1=p[2:1], p2=p[4:3])
f2 <- function() {
  do.call(distCosine, pts)
}

f3 <- function() {
  p %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(dist2prev = distCosine(c(lon, lat), c(lon2, lat2)))
}
```

The help for `geosphere::distCosine` (you don't mention which library you're using) implies that the function is vectorized. This will be much faster than doing row-wise operations.

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(vanilla=f1(), do.call=f2(), dplyr=f3())
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq      mean    median         uq       max neval
 vanilla 21342.53 32076.194 39113.213 40463.300 45340.3695 80332.304   100
 do.call   371.34   444.391   617.022   562.337   772.5475  1228.161   100
   dplyr 19800.10 27304.895 35627.085 34618.692 42531.5415 66111.814   100
```

Answer (score 1):

If I give up on using distCosine and implement the function by myself I get a fast response as well with:

```
dist <- function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
  r <- acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2) * cos(abs(lon2-lon1))) * 6378137
}
deg2rad <- function(deg) {(deg * pi) / (180)}

p %>% mutate(x = dist(deg2rad(lat1),deg2rad(lon1),deg2rad(lat2),deg2rad(lon2)))
```